C# same method in different classes with different logic
I enourage with some little problem and asking for help. First of all, i have 3 cs files:

InfinityLoop.cs - stores infinity loop that working all the time when program is on. Its logic something like this: if its new day do bla-bla-bla(some things)

public static class InfinityLoop
    {
        private static readonly TimeSpan CheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        private static DateTime _lastCheckDate = DateTime.Now;

        public static async Task StartReminderLoop(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_lastCheckDate.Day != DateTime.Now.Day)
                {
                    await ReminderBack.RemindPersonForBirthday(botClient, update);
                    _lastCheckDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
                await Task.Delay(CheckInterval);
            }
        }
    }


ReminderBack.cs - static object with only one method that comparing user input date and Today date

public static class ReminderBack
    {
        public static async Task RemindPersonForBirthday(ITelegramBotClient botClient,
 Update update)
        {
            var currDate = DateTime.Today;
            var cache = update.GetCacheData<UserCache>();

            foreach (var user in cache.ScheduleDict)
            {
                if (user.Value.Month.Equals(currDate.Month) && user.Value.Day.Equals(currDate.Day))
                {
                    var message = $"Today is {user.Key}'s birthday!";
                    _ = await PRTelegramBot.Helpers.Message.Send(botClient, update, message);
                }
                else if (user.Value.Month.Equals(currDate.Month) && user.Value.Day.Equals(currDate.Day + 1))
                {
                    var message = $"{user.Key}'s birthday is tomorrow!";
                    _ = await PRTelegramBot.Helpers.Message.Send(botClient, update, message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

3.CalendarCommandHandler.cs - in this object we interested only in one method PickDate(). The first thing it inputs picked date into messenger, then caching date and after that it uses ReminderBack obejct.
public static async Task PickDate(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update)
        {
            if (update.CallbackQuery?.Data is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                var command = InlineCallback<CalendarTCommand>.GetCommandByCallbackOrNull(update.CallbackQuery.Data);

                var data = command.Data.Date;

                var message = $"Picked date: <b>{data:dd.MM.yyyy}</b>";
                await PRTelegramBot.Helpers.Message.Edit(botClient, update, message);

                //caching date
                var cache = update.GetCacheData<UserCache>();
                cache.DateT = data;
                CacheCommand.UpdateCache(update, cache.PersonName ?? "unknown", cache.DateT);


                await ReminderBack.RemindPersonForBirthday(botClient, update);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

So, what`s wrong?
I want one method to perform different logic in different classes in order not to write another similar method, because every time I call the PickDate method, it goes through the dictionary and checks all the people, and not the specific one with which I work.
Did not use anything, just need advice on how to keep the code clean and do not write similar method

It is not clear what you are asking. I suggest you use translation tools or some GPT AI to translate from you native language in English.
You might be looking for and additional class exposing a method and that class would be used in all others, ideally injecting it, rather than using static methods (loosely coupled). Or you might want an abstract class that you can extend where "the method" is shared by all implementations, or just an interface.

You could eighter work with Interfaces, or with abstraction. Define the PickDate function in your interface or make a BaseClass that has an abstract or virtual PickDate function.
Then inherit from the interface (if you, work with the interface at your caller) or the BaseClasse.
